# Unable to properly download cyrillic-encoded HTML page in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to download HTML webpage locally to my computer and this works fine, however, it is a Bulgarian article and it does not seem to display properly afterwards.

I have tried many encoding (Code Page Identifiers - WINDOWS-1251, UTF-8, etc.) from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx but for some reason I cannot get it to open as intended.

For example:
Стара планина - величествената кръстница на Балканския полуостров

Displays as:
??N�?�N�?� ???�?�???????� - ???�?�??N�?�N?N�???�???�N�?� ??N�NSN?N�????N�?� ???� ?�?�?�???�??N?????N? ?????�N???N?N�N�????

Below I am posting my simple code. Your help will be much appreciated! :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace pageDownloader
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void DownloadPage()
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string webpage = client.DownloadString("http://www.nasamnatam.com/statia/Stara_planina_velichestvenata_krystnica_na_Balkanskiia_poluostrov-2525.html");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test\downloadedpage.html", webpage, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            DownloadPage();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Displays in what?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right encoding? I just reproduced this in Net Core, writing with `Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")` and it works fine.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply,
Are you trying with a cyrillic webpage? You may try with the one which I have listed, it is in Bulgarian language.
For English ones, I know that it works fine.
Thanks!

Comment: I am using your page. It comes out in Bulgarian.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rbQ0t2EC is the net core variant. This is what it gets you `downloadedpage.html: HTML document text, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string htmlCode = "";
    WebClient client = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
    byte[] reply = client.DownloadData($"http://www.nasamnatam.com/statia/Stara_planina_velichestvenata_krystnica_na_Balkanskiia_poluostrov-2525.html");

    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            Encoding encoding1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
    var convertedBytes = Encoding.Convert(encoding1251, Encoding.UTF8, reply);
    htmlCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(convertedBytes);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).